# 5 independent traffic lights, how many is car expected to pass without getting stopped

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$ I can't wrap my mind around this one. I keep thinking it is geometric probability problem, but can't get correct solution (which is $\E(X) = 0.6598)$.

Problem :

> There are **5 independent** traffic lights, each with chance of stopping a car equal to **0.6**.
>   How many traffic lights is the car expected to pass before being stopped - what is $\E(X)$?

Comment: What is the _definition_ of expectation? Are you able to apply it in this case?

Comment: Well, it is seem I also wrong. My answer is $ \sum_{n=0}^{5} n*0.4^n*0.6  = 0.63936$

Comment: Hint:  if $n=5$ there is no next light.

Comment: General point:  one good way to avoid errors of this type is to add the probabilities of your events.  You are supposed to be looking at all possibilities, so your probabilities should add to $1$.  In your case, your probabilities add to less than $1$.

Comment: @lulu, you right. so the answer is  $5*0.4^5 + \sum_{n=0}^{4} n*0.4^n*0.6  = 0.65984$

Comment: If a car does manage to go through all five lights, does it make sense to ask how many lights it gets through _before being stopped_?

Comment: @Arthur: Arguably not, but if you set $X=5$ in that case you do get the expectation the OP wants to get.

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, I had that same thought. Let's imagine that there's a stop sign after the $5$ lights.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for that point, but I can't see how to "add the probabilities" is done easily. I mean, what actually could I do in order to verify I'm not wrong ?

Comment: @lulu One could also imagine that the author of the problem really meant "How many green lights is the car expected to just drive through without stopping?"

Comment: @d_e  Yes, that's the value.  It matches the desired answer so I expect it's what was intended though, as Arthur points out, the language isn't entirely sound.

Comment: @Arthur.  That's a different problem.  If, say, our driver makes it through all but $\#2$ then I'd say he "drove through $4$ lights", not $1$.

Comment: @d_e  According to your first attempt, the probability that the string of passed lights has length $n$ is $p_n=.4^n\times .6$.  We are meant to have $\sum_1^5 p_n=1$ but that check fails with your value of $p_n$.  That means that there is a problem somewhere.  Either you are missing a possible event or (as is the case here) one of your probabilities ($p_5$ as it happens) is too low.

Comment: @d_e can you explain a little how you arrived at that solution?

Comment: @Reygoch, I wrote an answer. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of passing no traffic lights at is $0.6$
The chance of passing *exactly*  $1$ traffic light is: $0.4 \cdot 0.6$ - that because we have to pass the first light *and* stop at the second.
following the same line, the chance of passing *exactly* $2$ traffic lights is: $0.4^2 \cdot 0.6$
The spacial case is passing *exactly* $5$ lights which is $0.4^5$ (we have no chance of passing new lights after that).
So, summing it all, we have:

$$E(X) =  5 \cdot 0.4^5 + \sum_{n=0}^{4} n \cdot 0.4^n \cdot 0.6  = 0.65984$$